# How do I insert records from one XML file into another at specific points based on multiple criteria?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files that I want to merge together.  I am using OXYGEN software to do that via XML Sytlesheets. File 2 adds more details to file 1 adding an entry profile to each student that needs one.  My current xsl code (below) seems to work but it adds the entry profile at the bottom of the Student node whereas I want to add it after `<YRPRG>`.  The files match on both `<PIDM>` and `<NUMHUS>`.  I don't think this is too hard but I'm new to XML and just can't seem to make it work.  Can anyone help solve this please?

File 1 (XML):

```
<institution>
    <student>
        <PIDM>1</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>12</NUMHUS>
        <YRPRG>1</YRPRG>
        <Something>
            <term>7</term>
            <shortDescription>8</shortDescription>
        </Something>
    </student>

    <student>
        <PIDM>2</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
        <YRPRG>2</YRPRG>
        <something>
            <term>70</term>
            <shortDescription>80</shortDescription>
        </something>
    </student>

    <student>
        <PIDM>34</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
        <YRPRG>1</YRPRG>
        <Something>
            <term>5</term>
            <shortDescription>7</shortDescription>
        </Something>
    </student>
</institution>
```

File 2 (XML):

```
<studentstoadd>
    <entryprofile>
        <PIDM>1</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>12</NUMHUS>
        <PREVINST>1U40608</PREVINST>
        <QUALENT3>1HUK</QUALENT3>
        <WELBACC>1</WELBACC>
    </entryprofile>

    <entryprofile>
        <PIDM>2</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
        <PREVINST>2U40608</PREVINST>
        <QUALENT3>2HUK</QUALENT3>
        <WELBACC>2</WELBACC>
    </entryprofile>

    <entryprofile>
        <PIDM>2</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>2</NUMHUS>
        <DOMICILE>XK</DOMICILE>
        <QUALENT3>3HUK</QUALENT3>
        <WELBACC>3</WELBACC>
    </entryprofile>
</studentstoadd>
```

Desired output (XML):

```
<institution>
    <student>
        <PIDM>1</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>12</NUMHUS>
        <YRPRG>1</YRPRG>
        <entryprofile>
            <PREVINST>1U40608</PREVINST>
            <QUALENT3>1HUK</QUALENT3>
            <WELBACC>1</WELBACC>
        </entryprofile>
        <Something>
            <term>7</term>
            <shortDescription>8</shortDescription>
        </Something>
    </student>

    <student>
        <PIDM>2</PIDM>
        <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
        <YRPRG>2</YRPRG>
        <entryprofile>
            <PREVINST>2U40608</PREVINST>
            <QUALENT3>2HUK</QUALENT3>
            <WELBACC>2</WELBACC>
        </entryprofile>
        <something>
            <term>70</term>
            <shortDescription>80</shortDescription>
        </something>
    </student>
</institution>
```

My stylesheet contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile[PIDM=current()/PIDM]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile[NUMHUS=current()/NUMHUS]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The files match on PIDM and NUMHUS and I want to insert the entry profile for the relevant student after YRPRG.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I think he is, considering he says he uses oXygen, which comes with a built-in XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: @Abel Oxygen is an IDE - I was asking about the XSLT processor that will be used in actual production. If it supports XSLT 2.0, they should be using a key for the lookup. Actually, they should be using a key in XSLT 1.0 too, although that is a bit more complicated to set up.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes, that makes sense (no keys in my answer, though, I merely focused on the original question).

Comment: Does it need to be XSLT? Because I'd be thinking of using a script based XML parser.

Comment: @Sobrique: normally when programming, you try to [Program Close to the Problem Domain](http://www.artima.com/intv/domain.html). In this case, you transform XML, for which XSLT is simply put, best suited and already tailored to this domain. Using a scripting language with all its quirks and imperative processing problems to do what can be done easier in a functional, declarative way, _may work_, but ultimately will lead to spending more time on solving the problem, and more bugs to linger to hunt you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a node after `YRPRG`, you should do so in a template matching `YRPRG` - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="YRPRG">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile[PIDM=current()/../PIDM and NUMHUS=current()/../NUMHUS]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: It would be better to use a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to lookup the matching entry in the other document. The exact method depends on whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (you didn't answer my question regarding your version).

Comment: How do I find out what version it is?  I'm using OXYGEN

Comment: AFAIK, Oxygen lets you select from several processors, including such that support XSLT 2.0. Will you be always using Oxygen to do this?

Comment: Whatever I am using your code is working and does exactly what I need it to do.  Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this.  It had been driving me nuts. And thank to you for your help too @Abel - apologies that the requirements weren't so clear I've never posted on here before so wasn't used to it.  Thanks both.

Comment: If the user doesn't upvote you, I'll do it ;). @MartinB, you can find the version a processors supports with `system-property('xsl:version')`.

Comment: Oh I see.  It says it is a saxon 6.5.5 xslt processor which implements the version 1.0 xslt.

Comment: Thanks Abel, didn't know about the upvote thing. done it now.

Comment: @MartinB: I believe you need to have at least 15 reputation, which you get after accepting a few good answers, or after you ask good (upvoted) questions, each upvote you receive will give you points, which in turn will give you privileges. I upvoted your question, but I think you need some more points still.

Comment: @MartinB about the processor: you can configure to use Saxon 9 in oXygen, it comes with the package, which implements XSLT 2.0 and (most of) XSLT 3.0. It's a major difference in programming and if you can, you should use XSLT 2.0 or up.

Answer (score 0):

> My current xsl code (below) seems to work but it adds the entry profile at the bottom of the Student node whereas I want to add it after

Change this:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile[PIDM=current()/PIDM]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To this:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile[PIDM=current()/PIDM]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which will add it *after* the `student` element, as you asked in your question. This works, because `xsl:copy` creates a s shallow copy (i.e., only copies the `student` element, but not its children). The following `xsl:apply-templates` applies the templates (processes the nodes) of its children. By adding the `xsl:copy-of` *inside* the `xsl:copy`, you make it a part of the children of `student`. By placing it *after* the `xsl:copy`, you make it a sibling node.

(edit) or change it to this, if you meant with your quoted requirement to put it as the first child of `student`:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile[PIDM=current()/PIDM]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Note 1:** using `xsl:copy-of` makes it impossible to further process the nodes (if need be) that you select from the `s2.xml` document. If you want to modify their contents, you can apply templates to them. To prevent mixing the matching templates with the original source document, you can use modes.

**Note 2:** you have two `<xsl:template match="student">`, without an `xsl:next-match` in either of them, so only the last one will match (XSLT 2.0 usual behavior, but may depend on processor, XSLT 3.0 it depends on `xsl:mode` declaration). If you mean to append two `entryprofile` for each `student`, write it as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:variable name="entryprofiles" select="document('s2.xml')//entryprofile" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$entryprofiles[PIDM=current()/PIDM]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$entryprofiles[NUMHUS=current()/NUMHUS]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note 3:** In the comments your wrote:

> *The files match on PIDM and NUMHUS and I want to insert the entry profile for the relevant student after YRPRG.*

But I do not know what "relevant student" means. It seems like a different question from your original question, in which case I suggest you ask a new question where you specify precisely where you have trouble with this.

### Big edit (based on comment)

From your comment:

> Thanks Abel. By relevant student I just meant students which have a PIDM and NUMHUS in file 1 that match a PIDM and NUMHUS combination in the file 2

Apparently, michael.hor257k was on the right track with his comments on your OP. You should probably tackle this with keys. However, since I consider that an advanced subject and you said you were just starting out, here's how to do it without keys (and you can ask a different question once you start learning about keys).

```
<!-- globabl variable, remove local one -->
<xsl:variable name="entryprofiles" select="doc('s2.xml')/*/entryprofile" />

<!-- change your copy-of as follows -->
<xsl:copy-of select="$entryprofiles[PIDM=current()/PIDM][NUMHUS=current()/NUMHUS]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Abel.  By relevant student I just meant students which have a PIDM and NUMHUS in file 1 that match a PIDM and NUMHUS combination in the file 2.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have tried implementing your suggesion but the entry profile is added below the student tag instead of inside it and the entry profile appears twice for each student.

Comment: @MartinB, that is because you wrote so in your original post, quote: _"but it adds the entry profile at the bottom of the Student node whereas I want to add it after "_. It was already inside it in your original code. Perhaps you meant _"as the first child of the student element"_?

Comment: @MartinB: I updated my answer to show how to make it the first child. If you have two entry profiles per student, it is because you copy/pasted the code from the notes, which was there just as an example (I don't know your requirements, I inferred them from your code).

Comment: Sorry, I posted "but it adds the entry profile at the bottom of the Student node whereas I want to add it after YRPRG".  I'd put the YRPRG in tags and stackoverflow had removed the tagged bit.  I still want it within student but after YRPRG.  I also want to remove the PIDM and NUMHUS lines from the entryprofile.  Each student should have one entryprofile but only if their PIDM and NUMHUS match an entryprofile PIDM and NUMHUS combination.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @MartinB, I have updated to show how to select one element matching `PIDM` and `NUMHUS`, michael.hor257k has added an answer that shows you how to add it correctly after `YRPRG` (which essentially follows the same logic). _" I also want to remove the PIDM and NUMHUS lines from the entryprofile."_ >> you keep adding requirements. Please ask only one question at a time at StackOverflow, have a look at [ask] for some hints.